# Is there any way to run same set of tests from 2 different classes twice with different configurations without duplicating code

Tags: java, junit, interface, configuration, testng

```
public class JavaFile1 extends frameworkClass {

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)
    public void setup(){
    setMailServer1();
    //setMailServer2();
}

    @Test(priority = 0, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest"})
    public void test1(){}
    @Test(priority = 1, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest"})
    public void test2(){}
    @Test(priority = 2, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest"})
    public void test3(){}
    @Test(priority = 3, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest"})
    public void test4(){}
    @Test(priority = 4, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest"})
    public void test5(){}
```

}

```
public class JavaFile2 extends frameworkClass{
    @Test(priority = 0, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest1"})
    public void test1(){}
    @Test(priority = 1, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest1"})
    public void test2(){}
    @Test(priority = 2, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest1"})
    public void test3(){}
    @Test(priority = 3, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest1"})
    public void test4(){}
    @Test(priority = 4, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest1"})
    public void test5(){}

}
```

`Am trying to run the testng tests from 2 java files in following order.

configuration1
   Run all tests from java file1
   Run all tests from java file2
configuration2
   Run same set of tests from java file1
   Run same set of tests from java file2

Without duplicating code, how to tweak the tests to run in above order? 
Note: class 2 cannot extend class 1 as its already extending some other framework class

Comment: Which test framework are you using -- JUnit?

Comment: testng.In setup() am trying to handle both the configuration. This can be achieved using testng?

Comment: @ArthiVigneshwari - Its not clear what you are asking for. Please edit your question and add samples of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan My goal is to run tests multiple times with different configurations.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan kindly see the below example. I want to run test1 to test5  with setMailServer1() and again run the same set of tests which are in different JAVA file using second configuration setMailServer2(). How to make first configuration run initially , run 5 tests, execute second configuration,run the same 5 tests again without duplicating code? Will testng or interface concepts will help me to achieve this?

Comment: @HenningMakholm can you please help me on this?

Comment: @ArthiVigneshwari: No I can't. I don't know the tools you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you couple your test class with an `@Factory`.

Here's how you do it [ I am using TestNG `7.0.0-beta7` which is the latest released version at the time of posting this answer ]

1. Define an interface which abstracts out the `setup` and `teardown`
2. Build one or more implementations of the interface defined in (1)
3. Use an `@Factory` implementation to produce one or more test class instances wherein each of them are injected with each of the implementations defined in (2).

Here's a full fledged sample.

Interface that defines the setup and teardown capabilities

```java
public interface ITestCaseConfiguration {
  void setup();

  void tearDown();
}
```

Implementations of the interface

```java
public class VariantOne implements ITestCaseConfiguration {

  @Override
  public void setup() {
    System.err.println("setup() from VariantOne");
  }

  @Override
  public void tearDown() {
    System.err.println("tearDown() from VariantOne");
  }
}
```

```java
public class VariantOne implements ITestCaseConfiguration {

  @Override
  public void setup() {
    System.err.println("setup() from VariantOne");
  }

  @Override
  public void tearDown() {
    System.err.println("tearDown() from VariantOne");
  }
}
```

Here's how the factory would look like

```
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;

public class MyTestClassFactory {

  @Factory
  public static Object[] createTestClassInstances() {
    return new Object[] {
      new SampleTestClass(new VariantOne()), new SampleTestClass(new VariantTwo())
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: @ArthiVigneshwari Please dont forget to accept the answer so that it closes out the question.

Comment: Sure..trying it out..will definitely do. @Krishnan Mahadevan

Comment: Am not understanding the Factory class implementation with constructor. For same test class (SampleTestClass) are we creating 2 instances with 2 implementations (VariantOne() and VariantTwo())?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. This was just for demonstration purposes. You are free to alter the `MyTestClassFactory. createTestClassInstances()` (the factory class) to instantiate different test class instances as well, if you need.

Comment: @Factory
 public static Object[] createTestClassInstances() {
  return new Object[] {
    new TestClass1(new VariantOne()),new TestClass2(new VariantTwo())
  };
 }

Comment: Can you please give a demo of parametrized constructor with Factory Class?How to invoke parametrized implementation(VariantOne() and VariantTwo()) using constructor in factoryclass. I tried but not getting expected results.Should the constructor have relevant params like TestClass1(String servername,String user,int port,String password)?

Comment: @ArthiVigneshwari - I would like to focus on answering the question in this post. I believe I have shared the required answer that will help you get past the problem. So please accept my answer to close this question. For your question, please feel free to create a new StackOverFlow question.

Comment: Accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can have your @BeforClass method in Framework class and have it paramterized to run it for configurations 1 and 2. I am guesssing your setMailServer1() and setMailServer2() method does the same thing except with different set of data.

code will look like :

```
public class Frameworkclass
{
@Parameters({"data1","data2"})
@BeforeClass
public void setup(String data1, String data2)
{
    setMailServer();
    System.out.println(data1+"   "+data2);
}
}
```

TestClass1 :

```
public class JavaFile1 extends FrameworkClass 
{

    @Test(priority = 0, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest"})
    public void test1(){}
    @Test(priority = 1, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest"})
    public void test2(){}
    @Test(priority = 2, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest"})
    public void test3(){}
    @Test(priority = 3, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest"})
    public void test4(){}
    @Test(priority = 4, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest"})
    public void test5(){}
}
```

TestClass2 :

```
public class JavaFile2 extends FrameworkClass
{
    @Test(priority = 0, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest1"})
    public void test1(){}
    @Test(priority = 1, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest1"})
    public void test2(){}
    @Test(priority = 2, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest1"})
    public void test3(){}
    @Test(priority = 3, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest1"})
    public void test4(){}
    @Test(priority = 4, groups = { "webdriver", "UI","helloTest1"})
    public void test5(){}

}
```

Suite File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="testsuit" parallel="false" verbose="2">
    <test name="test1" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestProject.test.JavaFile1"/>
            <parameter name="data1" value="value1"/>
            <parameter name="data2" value="value2"/>
        </classes>
     </test>
     <test name="test2" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestProject.test.JavaFile2"/>
            <parameter name="data1" value="value3"/>
            <parameter name="data2" value="value4"/>
        </classes> 
    </test>
</suite>
```

Output:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
...
... TestNG 6.14.3 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

value1   value2
PASSED: test1
PASSED: test2
PASSED: test3
PASSED: test4
PASSED: test5

===============================================
    test1
    Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

value3   value4
PASSED: test6
PASSED: test7
PASSED: test8
PASSED: test9
PASSED: test10

===============================================
    test2
    Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
testsuit
Total tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Thanks Nitish for data provider example.

Comment: @ArthiVigneshwari happy to help:)

Comment: Am looking for class level implementation as there are many tests(around 50 tests) in the class and wont be able to annotate each test with @dataProvider annotation. So I think factory concept is best to solve this particular problem. However this example is good to know.Will use this in future cases. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. @Factory looks more feasible for your case as it works on class level rather than method level